# Client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header

Tags: http, go, websocket, https, gorilla

I am using Gorilla Websocket package to implement a websocket.

```
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)

    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
```

I am see the below error

**websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header**

I printed on the header of my request, and I am seeing the below

```
Sec-Fetch-User ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest document
Referer http://localhost:4747/home
Cookie myGoLiveCookie=369d99fa-901d-4b23-a64b-4731247de304
Sec-Ch-Ua "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile ?0
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Site same-origin
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 1
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Mode navigate
Accept-Language en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection keep-alive
```

There is no Upgrade websocket or Connection Upgrade as per expected

I believe I am facing the exact same issue as [this one](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/gorilla/websocket/507/488770126).

Comment: As the error messages states and the request headers confirm, the client did not make a [websocket upgrade](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.3) request.  Edit the question to describe how the client made the request. Include code if possibe.

Answer (score 9):

If you are deploying the WS server in a VM and want this header to be there by default, update your Nginx config file like:

```
location /ws/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8089";
    }
```

**proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;** will do the job for you even if the client has not passed the headers.

Answer (score 3):

The browser js request ws connection method is wrong, the correct ws request code `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4747/ws");`.

A correct ws request header, each header in it is necessary, but the value is different.

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

the error has arrived because you called `/ws/:roomId` manually, this endpoint is hit internal from the frontend. you can go to the `index.html` file and print `console.log(roomId)` after this endpoint is hit from frontend, and that will conclude the error!